# String offset cast occured error in codeigniter

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

I am receiving an error of String offset cast occured error in codeigniter while displaying the table data in a drop down combobox..

here is the code:

```
 <select class="form-control" id="price" onchange="changeprice();">
                    <?php 
                    foreach($detail['price'] as $newval)
                    {
                        $key=key($newval);
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $newval[$key] ;?>">Per <?php echo $key." - ".$newval[$key];?> </option> //Error is in this line
                        <?php    
                    }
                    ?>
```

Please help me out thank you

Comment: what does `$newval` contain?

Comment: the price is there in the new value @ghost

Comment: i am a newbie please suggest me the relevant code to be change @Rikesh

Comment: I think it's better to use `foreach($detail['price'] as $key=>$value){`

Comment: not getting the solution

Comment: @GeetikaJoshi what i mean by that is what are the contents? edit the question and show the contents of `var_dump($new_val);`